# How to create a report in Workday, based on the "Worker" business object , where the columns are the last day of each month for the last 12 months?

Tags: reporting, workday-api

I'd like to create a headcount report, where each row is a department and the columns are the last day of each month, for the last 12 months,in Workday. I would like to create something that resembles the table below:

[image]

I am not sure how to create the date columns in my report. Could anyone provide guidance on this please? I know there is a field in workday which is "Last working day of each month". This will give me the last working day of this month. However I am not sure how to get this field for the last 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do a Lookup Prior Value calculated field like described in [this Community link](https://collaborate.workday.com/t5/Human-Capital-Management/How-To-Create-A-12-Month-Rolling-Turnover-Report-Using-Trended/m-p/167761/highlight/true#M37750)

Business Object: Trended Workers

Function: Average X Time Periods

Summarization Type: Sum

Field: Ending Heacount

Number of Time Periods: 12

Return Zero on Error: Yes